# How do I abort a Rust process?

Tags: rust, ffi, abort

I'm wrapping a C library that does some `malloc`s that can fail. The rest of Rust aborts on OOM so I'd like to do the same. There is `std::intrinsics::abort()` and `core::intrinsics::abort()` (what's the difference?) but they are both unstable.

How can I abort() with stable Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Rust 1.17.0, you can call [`std::process::abort()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.abort.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could call [`panic!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.panic.html).

However, if you can intercept a failed allocation, and return to Rust in a stable program state, I think it's better to report the error (using `Result`, etc.)

Comment: I presume there is a reason standard Rust code doesn't `panic!()` on OOM, hence why I didn't want to use it.

Comment: @Timmmm That's because Rust assumes unwinding will allocate memory, and that one OOM means nothing else will be able to allocate. Personally, I think it's [too pessimistic and causes problems](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/could-we-support-unwinding-from-oom-at-least-for-collections/3673).

Comment: Does `panic!` aborts whole processes, not single thread?

Comment: It's configurable what `panic!()` does. With `panic=abort` mode it immediately kills the whole process. With `panic=unwind` mode it works like a C++ exception.

Answer (score 2):

Because Rust code typically is linked with a C runtime library where `abort` is defined, you can import that function using an `extern` block:

```
extern {
    fn abort();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { abort(); }
}
```

Note that this actually differs from the `abort` intrinsic: the `abort()` function raises `SIGABRT`, while the intrinsic generates an invalid instruction (`ud2`), which causes `SIGILL`.

Hopefully [`std::process::abort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/process/fn.abort.html) will be stabilized in the future.